# Oblivious Amplitude Amplification

Tags: grovers-algorithm, amplitude-amplification

I've been looking for the OAA paper but I've been unsuccessful in finding it. (so any links will also be helpful)

My question is essentially this, given the state:

$$\vert 0good \rangle + \vert 1bad \rangle$$

If I know the amplitudes of both states, can I amplify the amplitude of $\vert 0good \rangle$ without a reflection by the initial state using the flag qubit only? What conditions do I need to satisfy in order to do this?

Comment: This should be the paper https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.1414

Comment: You mean you know the _amplitudes_ of both states, or you can construct an oracle (i.e. a circuit that flips some flag if the input state is as desired)?

Comment: @3yakuya I know the amplitudes of both states and have the oracle but it turns out it is not possible to do what I wanted to do either way.

Comment: If you have the oracle you can use the rotation as in Grover procedure. Do I understand you want to amplify amplitude _without_ the rotation? Not sure if there is a known algorithm for that.

Comment: @3yakuya Yes I was trying to not use the oracle as it was expensive computationally but like you said I don't think it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe there are known quantum algorithms based on amplitude amplification that do not rely on an oracle to flip the phase of the desired state. Popular algorithms using amplitude amplification, including Grover Search, rely on the same idea proposed by [Brassard/Hoyer](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9704027) and [Grover](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.80.4329), requiring an oracle.

Technically you do not always need an *additional oracle qubit* per se (see [Why is an oracle qubit necessary in Grover's algorithm?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2145/why-is-an-oracle-qubit-necessary-in-grovers-algorithm)) but in practice such qubit simplifies the implementation a lot.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote the question if you think it was worth amswering and was decent.